# How to self-host overleaf without docker?

Tags: overleaf

Is there any way to install the overleaf server without using Docker. I have already installed a full TeX Live distribution so I don't want to do that again in docker.

Comment: I haven't looked at the open source overleaf but you probably want to keep the docker container for sandboxing each project (overleaf runs with shell escape enabled, so you don't want to let the tex runs run arbitrary code on your server). But if space is tight you could probably arrange a modified docker container that shared a readonly texlive installation from the host machine,

Comment: Did you figure out how to run an Overleaf server without Docker? For the rare occasion when I remotely edit LaTeX stored on my desktop, I would like to try Overleaf instead of my current ssh and vi approach.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, if you think installing texlive within any environment was much work, you won't like setting up something as complex as overleaf. Having an isolated texlive in a docker container makes things easier, not harder.

So, while you could just look into the Dockerfile that sets up said docker container and do the same to your host, it's strongly advisable to not do that. So, don't do that. They probably supply a docker image where everything is installed already, so this is literally no extra work for you!